# How to set the active jQuery menu li item

Tags: jquery, css

I'm pretty new to `jQuery`. I'm grateful for any direction. I'm trying to set a `jQuery` menu item to `active` when a user clicks on a different menu item. I have a `ul` list with `li` menu items.  When first loading, I set `#menuitem1` to be clicked to initially select it.  If a user then clicks `#menuitem3` for example, there is a condition to check something and if the condition is not met, I need the initial menu item, `#menuitem1`, to remain as the active menu item.

Menu `ul>li` looks like this:

```
<ul id="adminMenu">
    <li class="ui-widget-header">Application Settings</li>
    <li id="menuitem1" onclick="loadAppSettings();">Settings</li>
    <li id="menuitem2" onclick="LoadView('wLibs', 'Libraries', this);">Libraries</li>
    <li id="menuitem3" onclick="LoadView('wDocs', 'Document', this);">Documents</li>
</ul>
var previousmenuitem = "menuitem1"

//initializes with
$("#" + previousmenuitem).click()

function LoadView(a, b, liObj){

    if(condition_not_met){ // if condition is not met, I need to set the previous active menu item back to active
        //remove active class from what was clicked
        $(liObj).removeClass("active")
        //set active menu li to previousmenuitem
        $("#" + previousmenuitem).addClass("active")
    }
}
```

I have tried adding/removing the `li` class with `ui-state-active` instead of `active`, or tried to remove `active` for all `li $('#adminMenu li.active').removeClass('active');` and so on.

Or with the select option and focus options trying to catch the select or focus and just quit if the condition is met, like this (I just have an alert here, but it wasn't even popping the alert for me).

```
$( "#adminMenu" ).menu({
  items: "> :not(.ui-widget-header)"
  select: function(e, ui){
    alert("here")
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this simply you have to use $(this)

```
$("#adminMenu li").on('click',function(){
$(".active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

and this is a simple demo

```js
$("#adminMenu li").on('click',function(){
$(".active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="adminMenu">
    <li class="ui-widget-header">Application Settings</li>
    <li id="menuitem1" class="active">Settings</li>
    <li id="menuitem2">Libraries</li>
    <li id="menuitem3">Documents</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul id="adminMenu">
    <li class="ui-widget-header" onclick="setActive( this, functionTrue() );">Application Settings</li>
    <li class="active" onclick="setActive(this, functionFalse() );">Settings</li>
    <li onclick="setActive( this, functionTrue() );">Libraries</li>
    <li onclick="setActive( this, functionTrue() );">Documents</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

var functionTrue = function() { return true }
var functionFalse = function() { return false }

var setActive = function( el, functionResult ) {
    if ( ! functionResult ) return false;
    $( el ).parent().find( "li.active" ).removeClass( 'active' );
    $( el ).addClass( 'active' );
};

</script>
```

The functionFalse emulates the `return false` of your `loadAppSettings();` function.

Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8h9sqmrs/